# Disable Webpage for all IE versions with PHP

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

My code is just working with from IE version 1 to 9 ...

If I change [1-9] to [1-11] it is not working :/

Can someone help me?

```
function ieCheck()
{
    if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-9]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {    
        echo "This website is not optimised for IE";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `[1-11]` does not mean "any number from 1 to 11" because that's not [how regular expression syntax works](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). `[0-9]+` instead would be a good tradeoff between simplicity and being technically correct.

Second, the user agent string for IE11 is quite different to that of all versions <= 10 and you will need a separate regular expression to parse it; the information you need is provided on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503.aspx).

Finally, considering that versions of IE starting from 9 are pretty standards-compliant (that's even more true for 10 and 11) you should really take another look at what you are doing here. I highly doubt that e.g. IE 10 will not render whatever your page is correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The character block [1-9] in the regex is just matching a digit at that position. Because "msie 11" has *two* digits in that position you need to match "one or more" to cover all your cases.

Change your regex to this and it should work:

```
/(?i)msie [0-9]+/
```

That will match

- msie 1
- msie 2
- ...
- msie 10
- msie 11
- ...
- msie 999
- etc

IE11 reports differently though so you need to look for the string "Trident" in that case:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

regex:

```
/(?i)(msie [0-9]+)|(Trident/[0-9]+)/
```

Comment: if(preg_match('/(?i)(msie [0-9]+)|(Trident/[0-9]+)/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))    .... This is not working .... preg_match(): Unknown modifier '['

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(strlen(strstr($agent,"MSIE")) > 10 ){ 
echo "sorry: not compatible";
}}
?>
```

Using PHP(Specific)

```
<?php 
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE)
echo 'Internet explorer';
elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') !== FALSE)
echo 'Mozilla Firefox';
elseif(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== FALSE)
echo 'Google Chrome';
else
echo 'Something else';
?>
```

Using java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInternetExplorerVersion()

{
  var rv = -1; 
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
function checkVersion()
{
  var msg = "You're not using Internet Explorer.";
  var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();

  if ( ver > -1 )
  {
    if ( ver >= 8.0 ) 
      msg = "You're using a recent copy of Internet Explorer."
    else
      msg = "You should upgrade your copy of Internet Explorer.";
  }
  alert( msg );
}
</script>
```